# SQL retrieve attrition over periods

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using snowflake and i don't know to retrieve the attrition as I want.

I created a test table to retrieve attrition results as follow:

```
       CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE "TMP_TEST" (
        "Period"  DATE,
        "Report_Period_M-1"  DATE,
        "Country"     VARCHAR,
        "Name"    VARCHAR
    );
    
    INSERT INTO "TMP_TEST" 
    VALUES 
('01/01/2021','12/01/2020','DE','toto'),
('01/01/2021','12/01/2020','US','tutu'),
('01/01/2021','12/01/2020','DE','tete'),
('01/01/2021','12/01/2020','US','titi'),
('01/01/2021','12/01/2020','DE','titi'),
('12/01/2020','11/01/2020','DE','huhu'),
('12/01/2020','11/01/2020','US','tutu'),
('12/01/2020','11/01/2020','DE','tete'),
('12/01/2020','11/01/2020','US','hoho'),
('11/01/2020','10/01/2020','DE','toto'),
('11/01/2020','10/01/2020','US','tutu'),
('11/01/2020','10/01/2020','US','titi'),
('11/01/2020','10/01/2020','DE','tuto');
```

as follow:

| Period | Period M-1 | Country | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 2020-12-01 | DE | toto |
| 2021-01-01 | 2020-12-01 | US | tutu |
| 2021-01-01 | 2020-12-01 | DE | tete |
| 2021-01-01 | 2020-12-01 | US | titi |
| 2021-01-01 | 2020-12-01 | DE | titi |
| 2020-12-01 | 2020-11-01 | DE | huhu |
| 2020-12-01 | 2020-11-01 | US | tutu |
| 2020-12-01 | 2020-11-01 | DE | tete |
| 2020-12-01 | 2020-11-01 | US | hoho |
| 2020-11-01 | 2020-10-01 | DE | toto |
| 2020-11-01 | 2020-10-01 | US | tutu |
| 2020-11-01 | 2020-10-01 | US | titi |
| 2020-11-01 | 2020-10-01 | DE | tuto |

I tried to retrieve the attrition by name but i missed something :

```
   SELECT DISTINCT(B."Name"), A."Period",B."Country" 
   FROM "TMP_TEST" A
   LEFT JOIN "TMP_TEST" B
   ON  B."Period" = A."Report_Period_M-1" AND A."Country"= B."Country" AND B."Name"=A."Name"
   WHERE B."Name" IS NOT NULL
   AND A."Name" IS NULL
```

The result wanted :

| Period | Country | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-01 | DE | huhu |
| 2020-12-01 | US | hoho |
| 2020-11-01 | DE | toto |
| 2020-11-01 | US | titi |
| 2020-11-01 | DE | tuto |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need discard last period names.
After, using `NOT EXISTS` check user exists or not in next period.

```
SELECT DISTINCT "Period","Country","Name"  FROM TMP_TEST T1
WHERE T1."Period" < '2021-01-01'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TMP_TEST T2 
                    WHERE T1."Country" = T2."Country"
                        AND T1."Name" = T2."Name" 
                AND T2."Period" = DATEADD(month,1, T1."Period") )
ORDER BY "Period" DESC;
```

If the name is unique in every period you can also use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `EXISTS`.

```
SELECT T1."Period",T1."Country",T1."Name" 
FROM TMP_TEST T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TMP_TEST T2 
              ON T1."Country" = T2."Country"
                AND T1."Name" = T2."Name" 
                AND T2."Period" = DATEADD(month,1, T1."Period")
WHERE T1."Period" < '2021-01-01'
AND T2."Name"  IS NULL
ORDER BY T1."Period" DESC;
```

Result:

```
Period  Country Name
2020-12-01  DE  huhu
2020-12-01  US  hoho
2020-11-01  DE  toto
2020-11-01  US  titi
2020-11-01  DE  tuto
```

Answer (score 1):

> Thank you for your comments, the attrition is the lost name from previous period during the actual period. And yes, i want to count only once each rows with the same data.

Using `NOT EXIST` for finding non-matched rows and `QUALIFY` to filter out "duplicates":

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM "TMP_TEST" t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM "TMP_TEST" t2
                  WHERE t1."Period" = t2."Report_Period_M-1"
                    AND t1."Country" =  t2."Country"
                    AND t1."Name" = t2."Name")
-- "filtering duplicates"
-- QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t1."Name" ORDER BY t1."Period") = 1
ORDER BY t1."Period" DESC;
```

Output:

[image]